# Getting the selected year from a customed year picker

Tags: php, datepicker, jscript

I have this custom datepicker which I named as yrpicker.

```js
$('.yrpicker').datepicker({
  format: "yyyy",
  autoclose: true,
  minViewMode: "years"
});
```

[image]

This displays only the year-format.

But my problem is whenever I select a year ex. 2010, and save it on the database, I only get the current year which is 2017. How can I fetch the selected desire year.

Below is my php declaration and my html form.

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
<label for="elem_school">Started</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker yrpicker" name="elem_yrStarted" id="yrStarted" placeholder="From">
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: is your jQuery hosted libraries are included on page??

Comment: Yes, it is included.

Comment: why you are using strtotime() function if you are selecting only year in php code.You can directly save the value

Comment: if you are selecting whole date like 23-02-2017 than you can use date('Y',strtottime('23-02-2017'));

Comment: how should i do it? I'm not really adept in php.

Comment: don't post images of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace

```
$elemgraduate=date('Y',strtottime($_POST['elem_yrGrad']));
$elem_yrStarted=date('Y',strtottime($_POST['elem_yrStarted']));
$elem_lastYearAttended=date('Y',strtottime($_POST['elem_lastAttended']));
```

WIth

```
$elemgraduate=$_POST['elem_yrGrad'];
$elem_yrStarted=$_POST['elem_yrStarted'];
$elem_lastYearAttended=$_POST['elem_lastAttended'];
```

Regards :)